# One AMD CPU core is always at 100% load while Chrome is just displaying a blank page

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium, cpu-load

Chrome and Chromium (just open a blank tab) consumes 100% of one CPU.

Now I am on Firefox and it works well. (But I like Chrome)

```
$ uname -a
Linux x 3.13.0-30-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:40:53 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- Firefox 
  [image]
- Chrome 
  [image]
  [image]

Chrome has no extensions.

Comment: Difficult to guess as such. Can you go to this address in chrome and see what all processes are running:
`about:memory`
We can then try and analyze further.

Comment: This should have been a comment back to the user asking for more information.

Comment: Here is `about:memory` page http://static.md/8bf3fd7c27e4683e68f325ac970e325e.png

Comment: Looks like Steam also does the 100% one cpu load. I had installed Ubuntu with an AMD A6-5400 CPU, and today I upgraded it to an A10-6800 without reinstalling the OS. I will try now to reinstall Ubuntu, maybe it was adapted to the old processor and now works buggy with the new one.

Comment: There does not seem anything wrong here. The lone extension (StaticShot) is something that you just installed to get this screenshot, I guess. 
Sometimes, certain applications create new files on the disk. This triggers other searching and indexing apps (such as baloo) to start. Check the System Monitor / KSysguard to see if you can pipoint the application which is using maximum CPU.

Comment: I reinstalled the Ubuntu 14.04. Nothing changes. I think Ubuntu may have a bug with AMD A10-6800 processor. I will try to install another linux distro.

Comment: Please add screenshots showing that a Chrome process is causing the CPU load and also post the version number of Chrome you have currently installed. Blindly reinstalling without analyzing an issue is a bad habit and mostly never fixes anything. Please use edit to update your question and use comments to answer on other users comments to your question. It's difficult to keep track otherwise.

Comment: Now I am on Ubuntu 13.10, same issue. [screenshots](http://static.md/6b5a9bc0-0872-11e4-9bbc-81a2887103af) . What can I analyze?

Comment: Now I am on [ElementaryOS](http://elementaryos.org/) an Chrome is working well (no 100% cpu load) (34.0.1847.116 Built on Ubuntu 12.04, running on elementary OS 0.2 (260972)). So what can be wrong with Ubuntu 14.04 and 13.10 ?

Comment: I moved back to Ubuntu 14.04. Now I am on Chrome again, but it works well now. The difference is that I have not installed [AMD Video drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64) yet (last time I had Catalyst 14.4). I will try again to install different video drivers until the problem will disappear (Chrome to not load cpu 100%). It's interesting that on ElementaryOS, without and with video drivers, the chrome worked well in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from AMD Video Drivers.

I reported the bug [here](http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1099).